# Is this answer still aplied to recent versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/q/107538/62483) for most of new users of Ubuntu, because all most all of them have a Windows system already installed.

Since there is only 1 answer, and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/107539/62483) has been create since more than 1 year ago, I think that there should be new answer related to new versions of Ubuntu.

Is this answer still useful 100% for new releases of the installer method has not changed at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't mean to sound overly aggressive, but why not check yourself? Boot a VM, add a CD, walk through the guide and fix where it's out of date. I think you'll find it's hardly changed much from a user experience, but I hardly ever use the CD installs myself so I don't know.

Content is bound to become out of date and if you *think* it's out of date you can either verify it's true and then create a bounty to have someone update/fix the problem. Or edit/add your own answer. Otherwise meta would be full of these poll-esque questions about should or shouldn't we update something. If it's out of date, needs fixing, or is just plain wrong then the answer will always be: "Yes! It needs to be fixed" :)

tl;dr you don't need our permission to fix something

Comment: Having done that today with 13.04, I can attest that it still largely works the same.

Comment: @FEichinger You should add that as a new answer.

Comment: @Lucio I have neither screenshots, nor details on what has changed at hand, so, my answer would be nothing but "Works the same on 13.04" - which could just be done by leaving the question be/making it version-neutral.

Comment: No, I was referring that you can create an answer **here**. Not on the other post.